# How do I run 0.0.0.0 on https?

Tags: https

So developing a mobile web application and I'm serving my files from a server running on my pc and exposing them on from 0.0.0.0 however in order to access `getUserMedia` I need to be running on https.

Is there an easy way to get 0.0.0.0 serving content via https?

Comment: You could use self signed certificate

Comment: ...and if your next question is _how do i make one_, use this, it's fresh - https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

Comment: Both are good suggestions and I think will work but I managed to find a solution without doing this. Because I'm using create react app I can export an `HTTPS=true` which will create the cert for me.